# Java program using rpc with errors

Tags: java, networking, rpc

Java program using rpc with errors.The first one is server and the 2nd one is client.
What is the error in this java(Client and Server) program?
The error window shows error at RPCServer.java line 34 and 86.
Check error window for the same.(Errors are in the code window at last)
Checked on Ecllipse oxygen2.Please help regarding the same.

```
//SERVER:-This is the server program (RPCServer.java)//
package demo2;

import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
class RPCServer
{
    DatagramSocket ds;
    DatagramPacket dp;
    String str,methodName,result;
    int val1,val2;
    RPCServer()
    {
        try
        {
            ds= new DatagramSocket(1200);
            byte b[]=new byte[4096];
            while(true)
            {
                dp= new DatagramPacket(b,b.length);
                ds.receive(dp);
                str= new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
                if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
                {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str,"");
                    int i=0;
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                    {
                        String token=st.nextToken();
                        methodName=token;
                        val1= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        val2= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(str);
                InetAddress ia=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("add"))
                {
                     result="" + add(val1,val2);
                }
                else if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("sub")) 
                { 
                    result= "" + sub(val1,val2);
                } 
                else if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("mul")) 
                { 
                    result= "" + mul(val1,val2);
                }
                else if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("div"))
                {
                    result= "" + div(val1,val2); 
                }
                byte bl[]=result.getBytes(); 
                DatagramSocket ds1 = new DatagramSocket(); 
                DatagramPacket dp1 = new 
                DatagramPacket(bl,bl.length,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),1300)
                ;
                System.out.println("result : "+result+"\n"); 
                ds1.send(dp1);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public int add(int val1, int val2)
    {
        return val1+val2;
    }
    public int sub(int val3,int val4)
    {
        return val3-val4;
    }
    public int mul(int val3,int val4)
    {
        return val3*val4;
    }
    public int div(int val3,int val4)
    {
        return val3/val4;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        new RPCServer();
    }
}

//CLIENT:This is the client program(RPCClient.java)//

package demo2;

import java.io. *; 
import java.net. *; 
class RPCClient 
{ 
    RPCClient() 
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(); 
            DatagramSocket ds1 = new DatagramSocket(1300);
            System.out.println("\nRPC Client\n");
            System.out.println("Enter method name and parameter like add 3 
            4\n");
            while(true)
            {
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String str=br.readLine();
                byte b[]=str.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(b,b.length,ia,1200);
                ds.send(dp);
                dp=new DatagramPacket(b,b.length);
                ds1.receive(dp);
                String s=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
                System.out.println("\nResult= "+ s + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new RPCClient();
    }
}


Error: 
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at demo2.RPCServer.<init>(RPCServer.java:34)
at demo2.RPCServer.main(RPCServer.java:86)
```

Comment: Can you point out which lines are lines 34 and 86?  It would be helpful to separate the error message out from your code so it's more visible.  Can you point out which lines are lines 34 and 86?  It would be helpful to separate the error message out from your code so it's more visible.  Can you point out which lines are lines 34 and 86?  It would be helpful to separate the error message out from your code so it's more visible.  Can you point out which lines are lines 34 and 86?  It would be helpful to separate the error message out from your code so it's more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    String token=st.nextToken(" ");
                    methodName=token;
                    val1= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(" "));
                    val2= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(" "));
                }
```

Comment: you can add " " at nextToken(" ") as delimiter